# BigQuery : Load from CSV into Bytes Column

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I am trying to load a CSV file into a BQ table through java code. The target table has a BYTES column. If my understanding is correct the data must be in Base64 encoded format.

So my CSV file looks something like this
abc,abc,YWJjZA==

YWJjZA== is abcd base encoded .I encode it in the following way

```
new String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(rawbytes)); //where rawbytes is byte array byte[].(UTF-8)
```

I am getting an exception like this during load

com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Syntax error: Unexpected "=" at [1:68]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.translate(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:106)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.getQueryResults(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:586)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$34.call(BigQueryImpl.java:1208)

I am facing this issue only when I am working with BYTES column

Please let me know is there something wrong with the way I write to CSV file.

Comment: import as string, parse later in BigQuery?

Comment: I believe Felipe Hoffa's suggestion is a feasible way. Can you try that?

Comment: Thanks @FelipeHoffa and Alexandre Moraes. Really appreciate the suggestion. I forgot to mention one thing. This CSV file is generated by my code itself.So what my code does is following. Read a string > Write to CSV > Upload this CSV to BQ. I am not supposed to modify BQ table schema.

Comment: Could you export your .csv to GCS or to your local environment then load it in BigQuery, as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#loading_data_from_a_local_data_source)? Furthermore, does your rawbytes array  contain just Bytes data?